# Setting specifc MIME type with MTOM

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

With MTOM, we generally use content type as "application/octet-stream" to indicate that arbitrary binary data will be sent and then we retrieve it by using DataHandler API.

But my question is can we specify content type as say "image/jpeg" and avoid the use of DataHandler API in Java based SOAP web services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good detailed example / discussion is provided in the IBM Redbook: Developing Web Services Applications, see pages 64-74

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4884.pdf

In the example:

PDF is mapped to:
    type="xs:base64Binary" mime:expectedContentTypes="*/*"

Word File is mapped to:
    type="xs:base64Binary"

Image is mapped to:
    xmime:expectedContentTypes="image/jpeg"

```
sendWordFile will be mapped to byte[] in Java.
sendPDFFile will be mapped to javax.activation.DataHandler.
sendImage will be mapped to java.awt.Image
```

Also see:
http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime